# How to log out user from facebook application, but maintain login from facebook

Tags: facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-php-sdk, logout

I have tried the PHP SDK (v.3.1.1), and the current Javascript SDK 
as suggested here :  https://developers.facebook.com/docs/guides/web/

now when trying to log out I have tried both FB.logout() ( for js ) 
and $facebook->getLogoutUrl() ;

as the documentation for both clearly state, these methods 
log the user out of the application as well as their facebook session.

But I only need to log the user out of the facebook application ( the test site ).

I have tried logging the user out of my test site, ignoring the facebook
aspect. But in this case, when the user clicks the login button again,
the login flow ( facebook authentication and redirect ) does not happen.

I also tried : ( as suggested by previous unresolved questions)

```
$facebook->destroySession();

unset($_SESSION['fb_' . sfConfig::get('app_fb_config_id') . '_code']);
unset($_SESSION['fb_' . sfConfig::get('app_fb_config_id') . '_access_token']);
unset($_SESSION['fb_' . sfConfig::get('app_fb_config_id') . '_user_id']);
```

however, when redirecting to the login page, $facebook->getUser() still
retrieves the user.

note :
as per documentation example, I am using php sdk to login the user to my test site,
and the js sdk, to render and facilitate the facebook login button.

additional :

the authentication i use is basically what documentation suggests :

```
<?php

define('YOUR_APP_ID', 'YOUR APP ID');

//uses the PHP SDK.  Download from https://github.com/facebook/php-sdk
require 'facebook.php';

$facebook = new Facebook(array(
  'appId'  => YOUR_APP_ID,
  'secret' => 'YOUR APP SECRET',
));

$userId = $facebook->getUser();

?>

<html>
  <body>
    <?php if ($userId) { 
      $userInfo = $facebook->api('/' + $userId); ?>
      Welcome <?= $userInfo['name'] ?>
    <?php } else { ?>
    <div id="fb-root"></div>
    <fb:login-button></fb:login-button>
    <?php } ?>
    <script>
      window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
        FB.init({
          appId      : '<?= YOUR_APP_ID ?>',
          status     : true, 
          cookie     : true,
          xfbml      : true,
          oauth      : true,
        });

        FB.Event.subscribe('auth.login', function(response) {
          window.location.reload();
        });
      };

      (function(d){
         var js, id = 'facebook-jssdk'; if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
         js = d.createElement('script'); js.id = id; js.async = true;
         js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js";
         d.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(js);
       }(document));
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: if a user is authenticated to your app AND loged in to facebook `getUser()` will always return the FBID. deleting the cookie works, but the sdk get a new access_token wenn invoking `getUser` the question is why you want to do that ? neither you (the app) nor the facebook user gains anything from it.

Comment: how about simply deleting the session cookie you have for that user? If you only delete your cookie then the user will still stay logged on  to facebook, but not to your app. The next time the user clicks the login button you create a new session for him.

Comment: @NitzanTomer I have tried just deleting the test site's session, but as i have stated, in this case, the js sdk's login button no longer works as expected.

Comment: @Rufinus, not sure what you're trying to say here "why you want to do that?" .  Basically, i just want the user to be logged out of the site, and the facebook association eliminated when the user logs out.  However, if the user decides to login again, I want the entire login process to behave as though a previous login had not occured.

Comment: That's a different issue, can you please show your code for authenticating with facebook?

Comment: @NitzanTomer, I added at to the question

Comment: I don't understand, I thought that you have a facebook login button, the authentication part should happen there, not in the php side of things. Also, please in the future edit your original question and append code snippets there, it's not very readable in the comments.

Comment: @NitzanTomer, I've edited the question, and yes I am using the login button that is facilitated by the js-sdk.  So far, login/logout flow works as documentation says.  However, I do not want to log the user out of his/her facebook session.  But just now, I realize why they strictly did not support it, so a fb login is not leftover if the site login and the facebook login occur at the same flow of action.

Comment: dont really see where you have a problem, on my site i have an optional facebook login to, and i can login logout all the time without loginout of facebook. on the other hand, i dont use the widget for login/logout. :-) see http://www.vwup.at

Comment: @Rufinus, it would be great if you could post an answer with code

Comment: @Alias: to complex to take it apart sorry. the key parts are the app uses its own session, the users are authenticated via their fb id (given from `getUser`) or email/password given by form. their userobject (from my DB) is then registered in the session. so even if there would be a valid facebook session, as long as my authentication methods are not called, the user is not logedin.

Comment: Wont not logging out from facebook when logged in via your app be against facebook.com policies ? https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/login-flow-for-web/#logout

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Taking your code, and modifying just a bit:

```
<?php
    define('YOUR_APP_ID', 'YOUR APP ID');

    //uses the PHP SDK.  Download from https://github.com/facebook/php-sdk
    require 'facebook.php';

    $facebook = new Facebook(array(
      'appId'  => YOUR_APP_ID,
      'secret' => 'YOUR APP SECRET',
    ));

    session_start();

    $userId = $facebook->getUser();
    if ($userId && !isset($_SESSION['fbdata'])) {
        $_SESSION['fbdata'] = array("userid" => $userId);
    }
?>

<html>
    <body>
    <?php if ($userId) {
        $userInfo = $facebook->api('/' + $userId); ?>
        Welcome <?= $userInfo['name'] ?>
    <?php } else { ?>
        <div id="fb-root"></div>
        <fb:login-button></fb:login-button>
    <?php } ?>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
                FB.init({
                    appId      : '<?= YOUR_APP_ID ?>',
                    status     : true, 
                    cookie     : true,
                    xfbml      : true,
                    oauth      : true,
                });

                FB.Event.subscribe('auth.login', function(response) {
                    window.location.reload();
                });
            };

            (function(d){
                var js, id = 'facebook-jssdk'; if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
                js = d.createElement('script'); js.id = id; js.async = true;
                js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js";
                d.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(js);
            }(document));
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

I just added the saving of the user data into the session.
Now, if you use this method, when the user get's into your page you should check if he already has a session, if so all is good no need to authenticate him.

When you want to log the user out of your app, but not out of facebook, just destroy that session:

```
session_start(); 
session_destroy();
```

That should remove all saved data you have for the user, next time he visits your page you can start fresh with him.

I'm not a php programmer, and all of the php I used here is from my (very) limited knowledge and what I've found around.

Comment: yes, i've tried this approach.  but as i've stated in my last response to you, i have just now appreciated why the facebook sdk's log the user completely out of the site and facebook.   for instance, a user pops up a browser and goes to the site, using the fb login, he logs in to the site, and in that same action he is also logged in to facebook.   if i were just to destroy the site's session, the user is still logged in to facebook because of the previous action, but he/she may not want this.

Comment: what i would have wanted is : 1.) user ( not logged in to fb or site ) logs in to site via fb login, logs out and fb session is also destroyed.  2.) user ( logged in to fb, not to site ), logs to site via fb login, logs out of site but fb session is maintained.

Comment: Of course. Facebook gives you the way to log users out of their platform, but if to take that approach or instead log the user just from your site is up to you and your application. You asked how to log a user out of just your application and not from facebook, that's what I was trying to help you with.  You can have two different types of buttons if you don't want to make a choice: "log out of site & fb" and "log out of site" and let the user decide.

Comment: As far as I'm aware you have no way of knowing if the user was already logged into facebook. You use their authentication machenism which includes a few stages, and you are integrated back into the process only after the user (1) logged into facebook (2) authorized your application and (3) and this is optional - the user granted you with the permissions (or part of) you asked

Comment: Yes, I appreciate the point, and perhaps I might even find a way to dynamically facilitate it.  But anyway, I just wondered if there was a supported method that I have missed all along.